# How can I remove the service and folder permanently?

Tags: cmd.exe

```
takeown /f  "C:\Program Files (x86)\AlibabaProtect
sc delete AlibabaProtect
```

I ran the above and killed "Alibaba PC Safe Service" via Task Manager. Then I ran the following:

```
rmdir /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\AlibabaProtect"
```

Both the service and folder were successfully removed. However, after I rebooted the PC, both came back. How can I remove them permanently?

Comment: Stop the service, disable the service, kill the process, then try to delete the folder.

Comment: Also, see if you can't just uninstall this from the Control Panel. Often it has an uninstaller.

Comment: Are you running an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Mark the service in the Services applet as Disabled, reboot and delete it.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please read it again.

Comment: @ LPChip, the service cannot be found on Control Panel. It simply does not allow a user to uninstall it.

Comment: @spikey_richie, I did run the commands on an elevated Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that the problem can simply be solved by deleting the "AliUpdater" task on Task Scheduler. AliUpdater will download and install everything again.

Answer (score 0):

I used Kaspersky. In the settings I blocked all the Alibaba files from starting up and running on the computer. After restart I could finally delete it.

Answer (score 0):

**You: I can't delete this folder?? I can't disable its service? Disabled starting on startup but it still does so? What gives!**

After much troubleshooting, I found out I got this folder and service from Chinese-owned music app Xiami, which needs it to run. Chances are you got it from some Chinese app you downloaded as well if not that, so to remove that AlibabaProtect folder you literally just need to find that one Chinese-owned app that uses it, in my case Xiami music app.

**You: I don't know which Chinese-owned app is using AlibabaProtect.**

You may remove AlibabaProtect folder+service itself (but not the Chinese app that needs it) by starting your computer in safe mode (google how to do it for your OS if you don't know) and just straight up deleting it without any problems.

**You: I deleted it but it came back?**

Do note that the Chinese app will download the AlibabaProtect folder+service again by prompting you to trust Alibaba Technology should you try to start the Chinese-owned app. If you deleted the folder through safe mode, AlibabaProtect should no longer be on your PC so long as you don't use the Chinese app it is affiliated with.

**You: Do I really need to remove it? Is it a threat?**

Now were it not a folder that

1. couldn't be uninstalled or deleted through primitive means
2. is unable have the services disable-able, bypassing even disable on startup
3. the uninstaller in the AlibabaProtect folder being a useless dummy
4. is not delete-able even with the affiliated Chinese app not running
5. requires admin access to delete it
6. supports the ever-blooming conspiracy that the Chinese government is tracking people and stealing personal information,

I wouldn't give a hoot. However, it turns out that it primes itself as something akin to adware to have mirroring characteristics of one and I'm not too comfortable having something like that about on my computer, despite me actually loving that Xiami music app that it got tagged to and myself not experiencing any actual ads or pop-ups. It's up in the air for you to decide whether to keep it or not.

**Disclaimer**: I used a third party uninstaller that removes entailing empty files and potential registry additions that may or may not skew the same experience you encounter, but there shouldn't be a problem if you're just uninstalling from Control Panel.